# Did Hussam Ayloush tweet that the [US] people want to bring down the [Trump] regime?

Tags: united-states, quotes

Hussam Ayloush is the long-time head of the [Council on American-Islamic Relations](https://www.cair.com/)'s LA Office.

Daniel Pipes is an America commentator and historian who is the president of the [Middle East Forum](http://www.meforum.org/).

Daniel Pipes [wrote about a recent tweet from Hussam Ayloush](http://www.meforum.org/blog/2016/11/cair-leader-calls-for-overthrow-of-us-government)

> Ayloush wrote, "Ok, repeat after me: Al-Shaab yureed isqat al-nizaam. (Arab Spring chant)."
>
> That second line is Arabic ("الشعب يريد إسقاط النظام‎‎") for "The people wants to bring down the regime."
>
> In other words, Ayloush unambiguously and directly called for the overthrow of the U.S. government.

I think reasonable people could differ on the interpretation of the alleged tweet.

Is the tweet real?  And is Pipe's translation accurate?

Comment: Perhaps we should also ask whether the tweet (if real) is calling for the overthrow of the government, or is simply a factual comment on current events, since (according to news reports of protests &c) large numbers of Americans apparently DO want to bring down the Trump regime.

Comment: @jamesqf he was also tweeting that California should secede from the USA, in response to the election results. Clearly he was expressing his own opinion and telling people to repeat after him.

Comment: Any person who has that leadership position is clearly speaking for it's behalf as well.  He certainly hasn't been removed from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At 9:16PM, November 8th, 2016 he [tweeted](https://twitter.com/HussamA/status/796219993226547200):

> Ok, repeat after me:
>   Al-Shaab yureed isqat al-nizaam.
>   (Arab Spring chant)

This was preceded by negative comments about Trump minutes earlier.

Translation of the Arabic phrase is explained here: [Ash-shab yurid isqat an-nizam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ash-shab_yurid_isqat_an-nizam):

*The people want to bring down the regime* (Wikipedia translation) or *The people want to overthrow the regime* (Google translation).

So, YES.